# Powershell update string in each file within all sub-folders

Tags: powershell

I have a set of config files stored in each subfolder within a directory. These config files only contain a single string in the format `XXX_YYYYMMDD` where `XXX` is a number e.g. 006, 007 etc, so an example string would be `006_20150101`. I want the powershell script to replace the `XXX` number with a new one in each of these config files. I'm using the below script to achieve that and it works fine. However, the issue is that it puts a new line character (`ENTER`) at the end of the string which I don't want. Any way to fix this?

```
$sourceDir = "C:\Users\001"
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem $sourceDir *.dat -rec
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "006", "007" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

Comment: What do you want to replace each with? I see you want to replace 006 with 007, but are the rest the same? Increase by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default set-content ends with a newline, use `-NoNewline` to not have this behavior:

```
Set-Content -path $file.PSPath -NoNewline
```

I dont know if u can use this but you can use regex replace to match the first 3 digits in the string:

```
$regex = "^\d{3}"     
# matches any 3 digits("\d{3}") at the beginning("^") of a string

"124_20201030" -replace $regex, "007"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! And thank you for the `regex` suggestion, I've used that now!